# Omnisharp não inicia (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

OUTPUT do vscode:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 24/06/2020 21:52:56
    Target: c:\Users\Wagner\Desktop\Nova pasta\Xistilishy\Xistilishy\Xistilishy.sln

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: c:\Users\Wagner\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.1\.omnisharp\1.35.1\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 15848

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.2.9200.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: StandAlone 16.4 - "c:\Users\Wagner\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.1\.omnisharp\1.35.1\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to 'c:\Users\Wagner\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.1\.omnisharp\1.35.1\.msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.4 - "c:\Users\Wagner\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.1\.omnisharp\1.35.1\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            CscToolPath = c:\Users\Wagner\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.1\.omnisharp\1.35.1\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = c:\Users\Wagner\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.1\.omnisharp\1.35.1\.msbuild
            MSBuildToolsPath = c:\Users\Wagner\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.1\.omnisharp\1.35.1\.msbuild\Current\Bin
System.InvalidCastException: Conversão especificada não é válida.
   em Roslyn.Utilities.EventMap.GetRegistries_NoLock[TEventHandler](String eventName)
   em Roslyn.Utilities.EventMap.AddEventHandler[TEventHandler](String eventName, TEventHandler eventHandler)
   em lambda_method(Closure , LifetimeContext , CompositionOperation )
   em System.Composition.Hosting.Core.LifetimeContext.GetOrCreate(Int32 sharingId, CompositionOperation operation, CompositeActivator creator)
   em System.Composition.Hosting.Providers.ImportMany.ImportManyExportDescriptorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_2`1.<GetImportManyDescriptor>b__4(ExportDescriptor e)
   em System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   em System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   em System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   em lambda_method(Closure , LifetimeContext , CompositionOperation )
   em System.Composition.Hosting.Core.LifetimeContext.GetOrCreate(Int32 sharingId, CompositionOperation operation, CompositeActivator creator)
   em System.Composition.Hosting.Providers.ImportMany.ImportManyExportDescriptorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_2`1.<GetImportManyDescriptor>b__4(ExportDescriptor e)
   em System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   em System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   em System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   em System.Composition.Hosting.Core.CompositionOperation.Run(LifetimeContext outermostLifetimeContext, CompositeActivator compositionRootActivator)
   em System.Composition.Hosting.Core.LifetimeContext.TryGetExport(CompositionContract contract, Object& export)
   em System.Composition.CompositionContext.GetExport(CompositionContract contract)
   em System.Composition.CompositionContext.GetExports(Type exportType, String contractName)
   em System.Composition.CompositionContext.GetExports[TExport](String contractName)
   em OmniSharp.Stdio.Host.Initialize() na D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Stdio\Host.cs:linha 57
   em OmniSharp.Stdio.Host..ctor(TextReader input, ISharedTextWriter writer, IOmniSharpEnvironment environment, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CompositionHostBuilder compositionHostBuilder, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource) na D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Stdio\Host.cs:linha 51
   em OmniSharp.Stdio.Driver.Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Main>b__1() na D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Stdio.Driver\Program.cs:linha 70
   em OmniSharp.HostHelpers.Start(Func`1 action) na D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\HostHelpers.cs:linha 29
[ERROR] Error: OmniSharp server load timed out. Use the 'omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout' setting to override the default delay (one minute).
```

[image: print do vscode]

[image: print da extensão CSharp]

Estava programando um jogo pelo unity e o visual studio estava normal, desliguei o pc e quando fui usar novamente se iniciou o problema...

Quando inicio o Visual Studio ele abre normalmente, porém ao iniciar extensão C# o omnisharp não inicia de forma alguma (responsável pelo intellisense/autocompletar) e da erro no console, tentei CTRL+SHIFT+P e restart no omnisharp porem da erro no console, tentei abrir projeto sln mas também nao mudou nada, tentei criar outro projeto e nada aconteceu também, oque devo fazer agora? ja tentei até desinstalar e instalar o vscode e a extensão C# mas o erro persiste!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua versão pode estar desatualizadas. Desinstale e reinstale a extensão C# no vscode.

1. Pressione <kbd>F1</kbd>, digite `ext show installed`, Pressione <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Clique no C# e depois no botão `uninstall` para remover.
2. Restart o vscode.
3. Pressione <kbd>F1</kbd>, type `ext install`, pressione <kbd>Enter</kbd>  e pesquise por C#. Clique no icone `install` para baixar.
4. Restart o vscode.

Ominsharp vai rodar agora.